# What kind of grouping do I need? SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report which displays jobs and the labour type associated with each job. It is possible for each job to have more than one labour type. EG A job has 2 different labour types. 2 rows of data are returned, all of which is duplicates except the labour types. The report displays it like this:

[image]

I want the report to look like this:

[image]

I know this is possible with a subreport that returns all labour for each job. I would like to do this in the same report and remove the requirement of a sub report. I've looked up detail grouping and don't quite understand if it fits my needs.

Comment: please display output with sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to group on the columns that match, then Labour Type becomes the details row.

You can group on multiple columns using "&"

Example:

=Fields!Field1_Name.Value & Fields!Field2_Name.Value

Comment: Perfect. I just needed to add a details row. The question was poorly answered but you nailed it. Thankyou!

EDIT:One further question, currently my detail row is on the far right, is it possible to have it somewhere in middle? EG 3rd Coluumn out of 6 columns.

Comment: Do you have  multiple columns designated in the designer? I would think you could place the text object wherever you like.  I would need to see the designer to better understand the question.